# Are the Starter Set rules compatible with the regular D&D 5e rules?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players, new-gm

Are the rules in the Player's Handbook different from the Starter Set rules or just more expanded? Can you carry your level 5 character created from the Starter Set forward into "regular" play?

Comment: Are you talking about playing informally with friends, or formally in an Adventurer's league or other official play?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate (though this asks about the PHB whereas the other question asks about the basic rules): [Difference between DnD 5e Starter Set and Basic Rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56318/difference-between-dnd-5e-starter-set-and-basic-rules)

Comment: I’ve added the [new-*] tags since this deals with the starter set, which has a high likelihood of being used by new players/GMs, and a new player  looking in the tag might be interested in this question.

Answer (score 17):

### It's all the same game

It was [part of the design of 5e D&D](https://web.archive.org/web/20151110164618/http://archive.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ll/20130107) that there should be different entry points to the one game. These ended up being:

- a boxed set of "board game" complexity (the Starter Set)
- a free version of the core rules with few options (the [Basic Rules](https://dnd.wizards.com/what-is-dnd/basic-rules))
- the full version of the game, with lots of options (the *Player's Handbook*, *Dungeon Master's Guide*, and *Monster Manual*)

But they are all the same game, and all completely compatible, and you can continue using your *Phandelver* characters with the full ruleset.